# Live title with dynamic update (AJAX+jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a website, where users can get inbox messages and notifications while they are on the website. (Like on facebook, you see (1) at the begining of the tile as you have notification)

Currently I have an ajax request which grabs the data the title has to show. It works liek charm but the issue is that this file is called every 10 seconds. If user has 10 page tabs though, this file is called 10x10=100 times.. if my site has thousand users, you understand how much load it would generate.

I though of running the javascript on active tab only but how can I update the title of all opened tabs of my website? Any other suggestion?

Here is my code

```
var oldtitle=$(document).attr("title");
var checker=function(){
    $.ajax({
        url : 'live_title.php',
        type : 'POST',
        success : function(data) {
            ... code ....
            ... code ....
            ... code ....

            if (sum>0) {
                $(document).attr("title", "("+sum+") "+oldtitle);
            }
        }
});
}

setInterval(checker,20000);
checker();
```

Answer (score 1):

A cache mechanism seems the right way to go.

First idea: use HTTP caching

Be sure to add a parameter as a query string with the current timestamp rounded to the previous 10th of second.

Be sure your web server sends the correct header for the HTTP cache to work. It's best with a GET request.

Example:

```
$.ajax({
    url : 'live_title.php',
    type : 'GET',
    success : function(data) {
        // code
    },
    data: {t: Math.floor((+new Date())/10000)}
}
// we send a request similar to live_title.php?t=142608488
```

Second idea: use window.localStorage as a secondary local cache.

Additionnaly to the first idea:

```
var getCache = function(t) {
     if (window.localStorage) {
         var liveTitle = localStorage.getItem('liveTitle') || {};
         return liveTitle[t] || null;
    }
};
var setCache = function(t, data) {
    if (window.localStorage) {
        window.localStorage.setItem('liveTitle', {t:data});
    }
}

var run = function() {
    var t = Math.floor((+new Date())/10000);
    var cache = getCache(t);

    var success = function(data) {
        /*code*/
    };

    if (cache) {
        success(cache);
    }
    else {
        $.ajax({
            url : 'live_title.php',
            type : 'GET',
            success : function(data) {
                setCache(t, data);
                success(data);
            },
            data: {t: t}
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I will give it a go and let you know :)

Comment: Question on the above.... t will influence the query somehow? Or just it will be there so server will get a fresh copy of live_title.php file

Comment: The localStorage does not influence the query at all: it ensure data are cached if HTTP cache settings are incorrect or if a browser is configured to skip the cache. For the "t" query parameter, it influences the query and that's its main purpose: the same query is sent during 10 sec and cached. Then a new query is sent for the next 10 sec. It just force the browser to ask a fresh copy of live_title.php each time the "t" parameter changes. On the server side, nothing really changes for you since the cache is browser-side. The server still sends a fresh copy of live_title.php at each request.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do what you want easily.

Moreover to optimize that, I would recommend to use cache :

- One time a tab calls the method which count the messages, do the query and cache the result to a simple file or in memory
- during the next 5 minutes, each time a tab calls the method, use the cache and do not query the database
- when the 5 minutes are passed, do again a query, cache it and so on.

Like this, on 100 calls, you have only 1 big request, others are like requesting a js or img files